# What are the default login credentials for Jasig CAS server?

Tags: cas, jasig

I am new to SSO, I hoped to install Jasig CAS demo web app and be able to log in inside. Pure research and testing. I've disabled ssl using https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Securing+Your+New+CAS+Server

However I either don't understand the meaning of the note, or I don't understand the architecture.

What is default username and password to login into cas server? What is the format the note implying? Should I be able to log in the app in the first place?

```
   http://hostname:8080/cas-server-webapp-VERSION/login (see note below) 

   You should see the CAS login page asking you for your username and
   password.  The default authentication plugin accepts NetID=password.
   Enter in an identical value for NetID and password and click LOGIN.
   If everything is set up correctly, you should see a page stating that
   you've successfully logged into CAS.  Congratulations!
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In fact, it depends on the version of the CAS server you installed. Better take a look at the `deployerConfigContext.xml` file.

Comment: Username-password pair corresponds to the key-value pair under `<property name="users">`. For 4.0.0, it's username = casuser, password = Mellon. It's a shame this information is not on 4.0.0's `INSTALL.txt`...

Answer (score 29):

For 4.0.0 version:

- User: casuser
- Password: Mellon

Warning: this information is not updated in the INSTALL.txt of the 4.0.0 version of the CAS server.

For old versions:
As the INSTALL.txt says, enter the same value for user and password, it doesn't matter which value.For example:

- User: foo
- Password: foo

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: you can found user/password in /etc/cas/cas.properties eg:accept.authn.users=casuser::Mellon

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 4.2.6 version.

I found the username and password under below details. 
File Name : cas.properties

File Path : {cas-webapp-version.war}/WEB-INF/

Property  : accept.authn.users

It looked something like **accept.authn.users=casuser::Mellon**

From the above Username is **casuser** and password is **Mellon**.

This worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I too couldn't understand the note in the first place. Tried logging in using NetID as the username and password as the password. It didn't let me in. Later tried logging using password for both username and password and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

By default, It accepts same username and passowrd, i mean the username will be used for username and it will also be used for password as well.
For example: username: admin Password: admin
username: foo Password: foo